# Display text only in a merge master document (not in the resulting merged document)

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007, mail-merge

I'd like to put some instructional text in a Word 2007 merge master document, but upon merging, not have the text present (or at least, not visible).

The text won't print, because it is hidden, but even so, it would be nice if it weren't in the final document.

Is there a way to do this? I'd be content with any solution that will provide visible text. A field code that can tell if the document is a master document would be great, e.g. `{ IF [IsMergeMasterDocument] = "True" "the text" ""}`. Or some kind of comment or note that goes away during a merge.

(For the curious, the text tells the user that there are field codes present hiding some content and they must turn on field code viewing or press Shift-F9 to see them).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are on the right track with an IF field. Do you have control of the datasource? If so, you can include a field with an empty value (let's call it IsMerged) and then use this: `{ IF [IsMerged] <> "" "the text" ""}`